# A simple question from mathematical analysis (assumption changed)

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Let $\forall n=0,1,2,\dots$, $\alpha_{n}(x)$ are POLYNOMIALS in $x$. Next, let for all $x\neq0$ the power series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{n}(x)t^{n}$$
has positive radius of convergence. Can one say the radius of convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{n}(0)t^{n}$$
is also positive?

My quess is NO, but I have no example.

Comment: As you suspect, there are easy counterexamples.  Take any $\alpha_n$ with $\alpha_n(0) = n!$ and $\alpha_n(x) = 0$ for $|x| \geq 1/n$.  Then for non-zero $x$ the series is a polynomial, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n!t^n$ diverges except at 0.

Comment: No. Consider series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!e^{-n^2x^2}t^n$.

Comment: Very nice example, thx!

Comment: Let's make it a little bit more difficult. Suppose, in addition, $\alpha_{n}(x)$ is a POLYNOMIAL in $x$.

Answer (score 4):

Still no:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n!\left(1-\frac{x^2}n\right)^{n^3}t^n.
$$

Comment: I was wondering if there are still counter-examples when the power series is assumed to be convergent for all *complex* values of $x\neq 0$. Using Cauchy's formula it appears at first that some control exists on $\alpha_n(0)$, although there is a swap in quantifiers that needs some looking carefully, which I don't have that much time to do right now...